# including Python.h in C++ file CDT

Tags: c++, python, eclipse-cdt, embedding

I apologize if this is a silly question. But I tried to google this and I couldn't find anything to point me in the right direction. I'd just like to understand what I need to do to 'set-up' cdt to 'understand' my python.h include.

the erroneous statement is this:

```
#include <Python.h>
```

but I also tried

```
#include "Python.h"
```

And CDT responds with an error sign on the side stating:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- fatal error: Python.h: No such file or 
 directory
- Unresolved inclusion: <Python.h>
```

I am using Eclipse CDT Juno on Ubuntu 12.04. Any pointers would be great!

Comment: Where is `Python.h` in the filesystem and has that path been added to the compilers include path?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. Could you instruct me how to do so? I wouldn't know how to find the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see this path of how to setup the environment in order to use cpython.

1. [fully detailed tutorial for Linux](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Extending_with_C)
2. A small [github](https://github.com/zozo123/cpython-module) project contains all the relevant files to use on MAC OSx.
3. use python-config in order to get the paths to `Python.h` and to the static lib of python, which you should link your code with.

Answer (score 1):

Find the path with:

```
find / -iname python.h
```

Once you have the path, add it to:

```
Project > Properties > GCC C++ Compiler > Includes
```

If needed, add:

```
python2.7
```

to:

```
GCC C++ Linker > Libraries
```

Answer (score 0):

after installing the `python-devel`, locate On Terminal(ctrl+shift+t) by `locate Python.h` > the result is the file , copy the path and add it to eclipse by the following instructions.

personaly i like to get in the gist of the code so im adding to the compiler includes. but you can add to the linker as well, as mentioned above.

On eclipse : 
`Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > ...Compiler(*) > Includes > Include paths (-l)`

Directory : paste the path you've located in terminal.
for example`/usr/include/python2.7` 
press OK
see it was added to the list
press OK
.
enjoy

(*)note: if you are compiling c project choose the include under '.. GCC Copmiler'
for C++ '..G++ Compiler'